# Urgent question regarding resistance of water

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, ohms-law

I have mentioned before that I am currently in the middle of a university project where I am discussing electrical safety of water.

I want to work out what the current would be at mains electricity voltage (240V.) I have done many calculations and have eventually gotten values by calculating resistance at low voltages and then by Ohms law finding out what the voltage would be at 240 volts.

One thing I know is that the molecules of the water change when electricity is applied.  Surely it affects the values.

- Would the value deviate much from the calculation I have done?
- What actually happens to the molecules at 240V compared to 3V?
- Does higher voltag simply accelerate the processes that happen at lower voltages?
- If so, how can I recreate what would happen to the water at 240V so I can get a value without actually having to apply 240V?
- Would arcing through water happen at that voltage as well?
  I am sorry if this is not worded correctly, but I  am panicking as I have this due in very soon so need to settle this soon and I need a value I can use at a high voltage so I can accurately say what current I’d get at high voltage

I did a 9V experiment and got was 2.3 milliamps which means a resistance of approx 3913 ohms. This means at 240V if resistance stayed the same, I’d get a current of 61 milliamps. I’ve been told even with the changes it’ll still be around that ballpark from the calculation.

Is this a valid enough answer to make it not worth doing a 240V experiment as I don’t really want to do something that dangerous for both myself and my electricity.

Comment: Your experiment isn't simply water - it's water and some electrode, that undergoes electrochemical effects, and it's essential to consider those effects. Please [edit] your post to include specific details about your electrode materials.

Comment: It will also depend on the amount of dissolved salts and other chemicals in the water. You will want to control that, probably to the maximum level you think might be encountered under worst-case conditions.

Comment: @You don't have to jump from 9 V DC to 240 V AC. You could plot a graph by trying several DC voltages up to, say, 50 V, which is unlikely to kill you. Although you might want to make sure there is someone sensible around who won't panic if something goes wrong. Then you can find out what equipment is available in the lab for doing the experiment with up to 50 V AC and see if there is a relationship with the graph for DC.

Comment: *I have done many calculations and have eventually got values by calculating resistance at low voltages* <-- why don't you repeat those calculations at 240 volts rather than guess it is proportional?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Funnily enough I’ve just done it up to 36 volts, the resistance does go down (done 9 to 36) but eventually it stabilises, (apparently this isn’t to do with the chemistry) but I guess this means it’s relatively but not exactly stable till mains voltage?

Comment: @effectivedragon It will *very* likely be to do with the chemistry. As the experiment goes on, there will be more ions in the solution and the conductivity will increase. Also, the temperature may increase, another cause for a change in the conductivity. You could try with ice water. As for arcing, I suggest that you google for "big clive cooking with electricity" and watch a couple of those YouTube videos (and never let anyone else at uni know of their existence).

Comment: @AndrewMorton So I can test what may happen at high voltages by simply leaving the electrodes in the water and then injecting ions for a while as at higher voltage those processes are simply accelerated?

Comment: @effectivedragon I don't know. You're the one doing the experiment ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I mean would that be accurate, ie I want to get tap water in its most conductive state when it comes to chemistry “simulating” it in state it would be at 240v hope this is explained well

Comment: *I have mentioned before * No you didn't and what bearing does it have on your question.

Comment: What kind of project is this? I think you'd be expected to do the best job you reasonably can. So, if you can reasonably measure 240V then you should. Real cutting-edge research happens in university labs, so it's not a ridiculous request - there should be people around who know how to do it. One time I joked with another student about using an electron microscope and he said "oh yeah, I guess I could do that." If they *don't* want you to put 240V through water then doing measurements at lower voltages and extrapolating is quite sensible. Did you find a linear relationship?

Comment: @user253751 If your talking about from 9v to 36v the resistance started off taking a drop but then levelled out

Answer (score 7):

Resistivity of "water" is not fixed since you're not working in lab conditions with some reference water whose ion contents are well measured and known.

The "water" you deal with can be anything from a bathtub in a beach house with salty mist blowing in from the ocean through the open window, through highly mineralized water in the mountains, sodium-infused water from an ion-exchange water softener, etc.

There's a broad range of conductivity, and to get worst-case estimates, you have to choose some particularly conductive water that occurs in reasonably likely circumstances.

> I am currently in the middle of a uni project

What does your project supervisor suggest? That's where you should be asking that question too for sure!

> I’ve been told even with the changes it’ll still be around that ballpark from the calculation, is this a valid enough answer to make it not worth doing a 240v experiment

That depends on what you care about. If you care about some idealized notion of water resistance then the resistance can be assumed constant, up till dielectric breakdown occurs.

If you care about effective resistance with realistic electrodes interacting with the water, then surface reactions at the electrodes come into play, and the electrodes may well be injecting ions in the water and making it more conductive. So, in a very short time frame, the resistivity won't depend on the voltage. As you go from milliseconds to seconds, things will get quite dynamic and the fixed conductivity assumption doesn't match reality well anymore.

> The differences between different types of water is irrelevant here

> I am discussing electrical safety of water

Any such "discussion" is quite vacuous without looking at the range of conductivity and the various electrode-caused effects that change the picture. For example, imagine galvanic corrosion leading to a breach within a water heater, exposing the heating coils (elements) to water. The coil metal starts dissolving in water rather vigorously at that point and there will be lots of local heating speeding up the reaction. When you pour such water out of the heater, it may well look gray or black, and be quite a bit more conductive than the water that went into the heater. As you should imagine, that has some bearing on your discussion.

Comment: The differences between different types of water is irrelevant here all I’m trying to get here is a comparison between resistance at 9v and had i done the same 9v experiment with 240v whether the ohms law calculation at the bottom of my post is in the right ball park to the point I don’t need a dangerous experiment

Comment: @effectivedragon --  frequency may have much more of an effect than the voltage you're stimulating with.

Comment: @ScottSeidman so your saying it’s AC or DC has an impact and voltage doesn’t change conductivity much

Comment: @effectivedragon The voltage changes the reaction rates, as well as the current, causing varying rates of local heating. Reaction rates change to a "high" power of absolute temperature - higher than a square usually - so you can have a "runaway" situation where the water itself will go from low conductivity to almost brine-like conductivity in the matter of minutes, depending on how much water there is to contaminate. AC vs DC is a whole another story on top of all that. Water and mains is always a fairly unpredictable environment, so your approach is a first step but quite unrealistic.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica So you’re saying the heat changes is what causes the slight changes in conductivity. What do you mean when you say high power of absolute temperature do you mean temperature causing more conductivity?

Comment: What do you mean when you say realistic electrodes, I have been told by many sources that the new ions and reactions would not affect the conductivity much but would it change enough to make a big difference to the safety, I’m saying would doing a big experiment get much more an accurate result? On what my supervisor says he recommends to avoid doing the experiment where possible, he’s convinced there’s no major change to the point it affects safety but recommends I get more sources to verify as this isn’t a common experiment

Comment: Or even better, get several different kinds of water and then you can talk about the differences or similarities, as part of the project.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I am aiming for a rough value as if its rough the differences won't have much difference to safety, is my approach of calculating what current would be at 240v good for a rough value on what to expect?

Answer (score 4):

We usually refer to the *conductivity* of water rather than resistance. As noted it varies widely depending on what is in it.

There is a rather good backgrounder at [this page](https://byjus.com/physics/conductivity-of-water/).

Note that metallic electrodes in solvents (of which water is clearly a member) act as an EDLC (Electrolytic Double Layer Capacitor) so with the bulk conductivity, they exhibit a differentiator effect when inserted in the liquid.

You can read about EDLCs [at TDK](https://www.tdk.com/en/tech-mag/electronics_primer/11)

For a *single electrode pair*, the current should scale directly with the voltage up to a certain point; the behaviour in a multi-electrode (one power, others receivers) is more complex.